# Directory.GetFiles on network folder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, directory

How can I get Directory.GetFiles() to check a networked folder?

I have the following line of code in my project:

`string[] array2 = Directory.GetFiles(targetFolder, "*.zip");`

The variable `targetFolder` is grabbed from my appSettings files and resembles:`\\myNetwork\\Project\\TargetFolder\\`

However, when I debug my project, `Directory.GetFiles()` changes it to:`C:\\myNetwork\\Project\\TargetFolder\\` which is incorrect and fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `\\\\myNetwork\\...` instead (4 backslashes before UNC name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your network path should start with two slashes which are special characters, so you should use double on those as well:

```
\\\\myNetwork\\Project\\TargetFolder
```

Notice the four slashes in front (which actually represent two).